# Ordinary Differential Equations, finding equilibrium points and proving stuff

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem but I don't really know how to solve it:

$$x''=\dfrac 1 {x^2+1} ,   x(0)=0,   x'(0)=v_0$$
(a) prove that for any $v_0 \in R$ we have $(t_-, t_+)=R$

(b) for which $v_0 \in R$ (necessary and sufficient condition) x(t) is a monotonic function?

What I got so far:

(a) Look at $$G(x)=v_0^2+2\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac {ds}{s^2+1} = v_0^2+2tan^{-1}(x)$$
We will check that for G there is point $x^\ast$ in which $G(x^\ast)=0$ i.e., $v_0^2=-2tan^{-1}(x)$
And here I'm stuck because I don't really understand it. If $x=tan(\dfrac {v_0^2}{-2})$ then we have a critical point. But if not? How do I continue from here?
(b) To satisfy x(t) is monotonic we will require that it has no critical points (so $v_0^2 \neq -2tan^{-1}(x)$ but what is x?)....
please help! And if you know any good place to read more about this topic I would be super happy!

Comment: For (a), is $f$ globally Lipschitz?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know. I think that yes.

Comment: You need to do some work

Comment: @copper.hat okay, do you know maybe where can I find more information about it? To do the work?

Comment: This is homework, I don't know the context in which you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat this is not homework, I am just trying to study, but the notes of my professor are not helping me in this

Comment: What text are you using? Are you familiar with the existence and uniqueness theorem for odes?

Comment: @copper.hat yes that I did study, but we used Lipschitz continuity

Comment: Formulate the ode as a first order ode and show that it is globally Lipschitz for (a).